# Why is the database snapshot undefined Firebase Admin Node Js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

The following code comes straight [Firebase Functions getting started tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  let userid = 'afewfaewf';
  let dummyJson = {key: 'value'};
  let dbPath = '/' + userid;
  admin.database().ref(dbPath).update({dummy: dummyJson}).then(snapshot => {
    console.log('finished writing to Firebase database ');
    console.log(snapshot === undefined);
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

Here is the full output running it locally:

```
❯ firebase serve --only functions

=== Serving from '/Users/eric/AndroidStudioProjects/XXX/firebase-functions'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate HTTPS functions. Support for other event types coming soon.
Warning: You're using Node.js v7.7.1 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.9.1.
Server#addProtoService is deprecated. Use addService instead
✔  functions: addMessage: http://localhost:5002/xxx/us-central1/addMessage
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: finished writing to Firebase database 
info: true
error: (node:11005) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
(node:11005) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And on the cloud:

```
11:44:06.290 PM
warning 
addMessage
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined at admin.database.ref.update.then.snapshot (/user_code/index.js:32:31) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
    at admin.database.ref.update.then.snapshot (/user_code/index.js:32:31)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
11:44:06.289 PM
warning 
addMessage
Unhandled rejection
11:44:06.288 PM
info    
addMessage
true
11:44:06.283 PM
info    
addMessage
finished writing to Firebase database
11:44:05.322 PM
outlined_flag   
addMessage
Function execution started
```

Comment: Because that code is wrong. `update` returns a promise that resolves to `void` (i.e. `undefined`) - not a `Snapshot`.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#update

Comment: thanks @cartant, do you mind putting it in an answer so that I can accept it? By the way, could you elaborate a bit on how to use the "promise", is it some kind of asynchronous callback to get the result whether my update fails or succeeds eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @cartan for pointing me to the right direction

The original example "reads" from Firebase database so there is a snapshop value returned

My code on the other try to "writes" to Firebase database, there is no value returned but a call back instead.
I've changed my code to the following and everything works perfectly as expected:

```
admin.database().ref(dbPath).update({dummy: dummyJson}, function (err) {
    console.log("done with error " + err);
    res.status(200).send("success");
  });
```